# How to submit a form from layout page in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC 4 site I have a common top menu defined in the _Layout master page. In that menu I have a search input textbox, almost the same as the menu here in stackoverflow site, but I have a submit button apart of the search input text field.

How can I fire an action and submit that form to some controller when I hit that button? Is it possible in MVC?

Here´s the code of the form:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="teste" data-provide="typehead" class="form-control" placeholder="Procurar" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roger's answer is correct, but I notice your form tag has some HTML attributes, in which case you need to use a different overload of `Html.BeginForm()`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller",
   FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left", role = "search" }))
{
    // ...
}
```

The `@` sign prefixing `class` is required, because `class` is a keyword in C#.  Without it, it will produce an error.

The code above makes the assumption that you are `POSTing` your form.  If you're using `GET` instead, simply change the form method to `FormMethod.Get`.

Comment: Thanks John, it works like a charm. And the css style as well.

Answer (score 6):

Use the MVC razor syntax instead of creating your own forms:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="teste" data-provide="typehead" class="form-control" placeholder="Procurar" autocomplete="off"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
}
```

Comment: Your answer is right, but the other is more complete becouse he is concerning about the css im using for this form. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I know it is, but I am not the person who will build the code for you. I gave a nudge in the right direction, if you would have checked the parameter list it would be clear what was expected from the method :-)

Comment: Im not expecting that you build the code for me. If your post was the only one i probably vote as right answer.